# Issue with the NDSolve code

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

With this procedure, one may determine an eigen-value function $R(a)$ for any given $\Xi$ (say 0, 25, 50, 75, 100)

```
g[eta1_, eta3_, R_, a_, Xi_] := {f[1], h[1], q[1]} /.     
NDSolve[{D[f[x], {x, 2}] - a^2 f[x] + a (h[x] + R q[x]) == 0,
    D[h[x], { x, 2}] - a^2 h[x] + a Xi x f[x] == 0,
    D[q[x], {x, 2}] - a^2 q[x] + a f[x] == 0,
     f[0] == 0,
f'[0] == 1,
h[0] == eta1,
h'[0] == 0, 
q[0] == 0,
q'[0] == eta3 
}, {f, h, q}, {x, 0, 1}]
s[a_, Xi_] :=FindRoot[g[eta1, eta3, R, a, Xi], {{R, 0}, {eta1, 0}, {eta3, 0}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 100000]
```

where the condition $f'(0) = 1$ is a normalisation condition. 
But the problem is that the code doesn't converge always. The output I am looking for is like this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code to demonstrate *where* your implementation allegedly fails.

Comment: Well, for s[7.8,100], R=28 and for s[8,100], R=22, which is not what we can see from the above fig.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly and give us a simple template to check against the figure.

Comment: I noticed my mistake and rewrited my answer, I think now it's just what you want. Have a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for simple cases (the only case I can think of is monotonic function at the moment), results of `FindRoot` are often affected by the starting point for root searching. More starting points, more uncertain, so `FindRoot` is easier to fail when it's searching for the roots of a set of equations than that of a single equation. The purpose of your code is in fact searching $R$ that makes $f(1)$, $h(1)$, $q(1)$ equal to $0$ for given $a$ and $Ξ$, i.e. $f(x)$, $h(x)$, $q(x)$ will satisfy the boundary condition(B.C.):

$$f(1)=h(1)=q(1)=0$$

Why not use some of these B.C.s instead of the uncertain ones inside `NDSolve`?

After some trial I found that using $f(1)=q(1)=0$ inside seems to be the best choice, so I modified your code into:

```
(*
 h[0] == eta1 => f[1] == 0
q'[0] == eta3 => q[1] == 0
*)
g2[R_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, Xi_?NumericQ] := 
 h[1] /. NDSolve[{D[f[x], {x, 2}] - a^2 f[x] + a (h[x] + R q[x]) == 0,
                  D[h[x], {x, 2}] - a^2 h[x] + a Xi x f[x] == 0, 
                  D[q[x], {x, 2}] - a^2 q[x] + a f[x] == 0, 
                  f'[0] == 1, h'[0] == 0, q[0] == 0, f[0] == 0, f[1] == 0, q[1] == 0}, 
                 {f, h, q}, {x, 0, 1}]
s2[a_, Xi_] := FindRoot[g2[R, a, Xi], {R, 0}]
```

The role of those `?NumericQ`s is to quit the warning `NDSolve::ndinnt` and `ReplaceAll::reps`, the output won't be affected even if you take them away.

Let's check the effect of the new definition:

```
sample = Join[Range[6/10, 2, 1/10], Range[2, 8, 1/4]];
data[Xi_] := {sample, R /. s2[#, Xi] & /@ sample} // Transpose;
rst = data /@ Range[0, 100, 25];
ListLinePlot[rst, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {-40, 100}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

Some warnings still generate, but the result matches your figure very well:

[image]

And needless to say, much better than your original:

```
olddata[Xi_] := {sample, R /. s[#, Xi] & /@ sample} // Transpose;
oldrst = olddata /@ Range[0, 100, 25];
ListLinePlot[oldrst, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {-40, 100}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: lovely! thx mate